# How to construct array of values in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have to return a JSON string in this format using Spring. My Spring controller will take care of this since I specify the return value as `@ResponseBody`. Now I have to construct the value in Java in the following format:

```
["Male", "m"]
```

Please help me to get this done in Java.

Comment: The question is "OK". The title is extremely bad.

Comment: Now the title is somehow OK, the question still "OK" :D

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need an object that can be marshalled to json by your spring response provider. Creating a json like array wouldnt help you much if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Return `String[]` or `List<String>`. Either of these should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(
       Arrays.toString(new String[] {"Male", "m"})); // prints: ["Male", "m"]

// if the data comes as a dynamic List
String list = Arrays.asList("Male", "m").toString();
System.out.println(list); // prints: ["Male", "m"]
```

Comment: You'd have to use `Arrays.toString(Object[])` for the first example.